# JS div Popup issue

Tags: javascript, popup

I have some divs that appear on click of a link, but i am trying to make it so that when you click on a 2nd link to popup, any open ones will be closed before the new one opens. there should only be one open at a time.

the js...

```
<script>
    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        width: 'toggle'
    }, "fast", easing, callback);
};

$(function () {
    function select($link) {
        $link.addClass('selected');
        $($link.attr('href')).slideFadeToggle(function () {});
    }

    function deselect($link) {
        $($link.attr('href')).slideFadeToggle(function () {
            $link.removeClass('selected');
        });
    }

    $('.contact').click(function () {
        var $link = $(this);
        if ($link.hasClass('selected')) {
            deselect($link);
        } else {
            select($link);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.close').live('click', function () {
        deselect();
        return false;
    });
});

                            </script>
```

the divs...

```
 <div id='did_{$page_trackid}'  class='arrow_box pop_{$page_trackid}' style=''>  <img src='".$info4['Image']."' class='subtext_img'>
                                                    <h2 class='subtext'><a href='http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/dnb/".$info2['username']."'>".$info2['username']."</a></h2>
                                                    <p class='subtext'>".$info3['user_title']."</p>
                                                    <p class='subtext'><a href='".$info3['website_link']."' target='_blank'>".$info3['website_link']."</a>

                                                    </p>

                                                    </div>

                 <div id='did_2_{$page_trackid}'  class='arrow_box2 pop_stats_{$page_trackid}' style=''>  
                                                    <h2 class='subtext'>Stats</h2><br />
                                                    <p class='subtext'>Plays: 1m <br />
                                                                    Downloads: 527, 046

                                                    </p>

                                                    </div>
```

the links...

```
<div style='position: absolute; z-index: 2; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 699px;'>

                <a href='#did_{$page_trackid}' class='contact' ><img style='height: 20px;' alt='Posted by' src='http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/play1/skin/user-profile2.png' style=''></a> 
                </div>

                <div style='position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 20px; height: 20px; padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 699px;'>
                <a href='#did_2_{$page_trackid}' class='contact'><img style='height: 20px;' alt='Track stats' src='http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/play1/skin/stats.png' style=''></a>
                </div>
```

I have tried replacing the first function with

```
function select($link) {
$link.addClass('selected');
$('.arrow_box:visible').slideFadeToggle(function () {});
$($link.attr('href')).slideFadeToggle(function () {});
```

}

but that bugs out, with one pop over lapping the other. I have 2 classes for the divs(1 for each) so i attempted to add

> $('.arrow_box2:visible').slideFadeToggle(function () {});

but that too doesnt work.

Am i going about it the right way to close any open arrow_box or arrow_box2 when clicking a link to open a new pop up??

thanks

Comment: Please amend the tabbing in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your html and js into a jsfiddle and modified the `select` method. Try it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/wHyfK/1/

I believe this now does what you asked for. The key is to toggle any shown panes (to hide them) before toggling the new "selected" pane (to show it).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou, this works perfectly, i also see where i was going wrong. many thanks for the help @mchail